# How to handle PROPFIND HTTP Verb requests (or other) in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for implementation options how to handle requests with more exotic HTTP verbs like `PROPFIND` or `MKCOL` with ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET Core MVC.

In ASP.NET Core MVC you can decorate your action methods with

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPut]
[HttpPost]
[HttpDelete]
[HttpHead]
[HttpOptions]
[HttpPatch]
```

For a REST API or web applications these HTTP verbs are sufficient. For WebDav for example `PROPFIND` or `MKCOL` verbs have to be handled somehow, too.

Is there a possibility to extend ASP.NET Core MVC to support more HTTP verbs than the ones listed above ?
Or do you think that writing an own middleware component is the better approach to add WebDav capabilities to a ASP.NET Core app ?

I have looked into the ASP.NET Core Source Repositories to get some ideas. But I am stuck in the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is easier than I thought. You can invoke Controller Actions by a HTTP verb like this

```
public class WebDavController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/dav/{fileName}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string fileName)
    {
        // a classic Get method
        ....
    }

    [Route("/dav/{fileName}")]
    public IActionResult Propfind(string fileName)
    {
        // this is invoked if http verb is PROPFIND 
        // (framework searches for corresponding action name)
        ....
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("LOCK")]
    [Route("/dav/{fileName}")]
    public IActionResult MyLockAction(string fileName)
    {
        // this is invoked if http verb is LOCK
        // (framework searches annotated action method)
        ....
    }

}
```